# The Meaning of $u=c\sin\theta$ Equation in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

In the Introductory Special Relativity book, by W G V Rosser, page 19, the author is formulating the relativistic kinetic energy equation. In his derivation, he writes the following equation:
$$u=c\sin\theta$$
I have two questions regarding Equation (2.7), the above equation, in the book:

1. How did the author prove this equation?
2. Could anyone please explain the physical interpretation of this equation?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: You might have to provide more context (e.g., quoting the passage) as this really only will make sense to those who have the book in front of them.

Comment: The equation is simply the definition of the angle $\theta$. It's a definition so it does not need a derivation or proof. He did it so as to simplify the equation just as you make substitutions when doing integrals.

Comment: Note that I said *quoting* the passage, not taking picture with your cell phone and uploading it.

Answer (score 2):

In this passage by Rosser, $u=c\sin\theta$ is the spatial velocity, where $\theta$ is a parameter used in a "Loedel diagram" (see [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_diagram#Loedel_diagram)
and Paul Gruner's [*Elementary geometric representation of the formulas of the special theory of relativity*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Elementary_geometric_representation_of_the_formulas_of_the_special_theory_of_relativity)), which is a limited variant of the Minkowski spacetime diagram that tries to use Euclidean trigonometry instead of the more appropriate hyperbolic trigonometry (which uses the [rapidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity) parameter $w$, geometrically interpreted as the Minkowski-arc-length of the unit hyperbola).

So,
$$\text{spatial velocity}=u=c\sin\theta=c\tanh w.$$
[Incidentally, $\theta=\text{gd}(w)$ where $\text{gd()}$ is the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) which could be defined as $\text{gd}(w)=\arcsin(\tanh w)$.]

With the above definitions, the time-dilation function is
$$\gamma=(\text{Rosser's}\ \alpha)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}=\sec\theta=\cosh w,$$
and the spatial-component of the 4-momentum [the relativistic momentum] is
$$\begin{align*}p 
&=\alpha mu =\sec\theta\ m (c \sin\theta)=mc\tan\theta\\
&=\gamma mu
=\cosh w(mc\tanh w)=mc\sinh w\end{align*}.$$

As noted by one of the commenters, the $\theta$-parameter is a convenient choice of variables that make the equations of special relativity easier to analyze with Euclidean trigonometry.

There is a limited geometric interpretation of $\theta$ using the Loedel diagram.

A fuller explanation of this aspect would require a detailed treatment of the Loedel diagram.

*In my opinion, the Minkowski diagram and its hyperbolic trigonometry using rapidity $w$ is superior (and does not suffer from the limitations of the Loedel diagram). But I can't elaborate on this point here.*

Comment: +1 for the preference for rapidity.